# Waze Deep Links broken?

Tags: ios, waze

On iOS, I can't make **Waze navigation** works when I launch the app from my app. It seems [Waze Deep Links](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/) is broken. Am I the only one to have this bug? How Uber works for drivers if they don't use Deep Links?

Here is what I tried, even if I run the URL in my Safari mobile browser, Waze opened but nothing happened then *(and I have Waze installed!)*:

```
waze://ul?ll=45.6906304,-120.810983&navigate=yes
```

I found a relative question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358194/waze-deep-links), but the problem was on Android and mine is on iOS. It should work.

Comment: The deep links page now says not to even use `waze:`, but instead `https://waze.com/ul`, even for app to app linking. The docs are wrong, however. The `https` scheme doesn't work on iOS. You have to use `waze://q=`, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48703425/6488573) by removing `ul` from the URL.

So, this link is working:

`waze://?ll=45.6906304,-120.810983&navigate=yes`

Comment: It doesn't seem like the "&navigate=yes" really makes a difference. Did you see a difference?

Comment: When I wrote this answer it made one yes, maybe it changed today ?

Comment: Thank you @cusmar. I believe the temp screen that shows up when starting a navigation / trip threw me. I didn't recognize that it was in navigate mode. :)

Comment: It works for me only by providing coords and not a readable address

Answer (score -1):

Another example that works: `waze://?favorite=home&navigate=yes`

Comment: I believe that is an Android syntax that doesn't work on iOS

Comment: if  UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) {  
//open the waze map
} else {
// waze not installed
}